# Show that $\mathbb Z$ with the finite-closed topology is a $T_1$-space but not a $T_2$-space.

Tags: general-topology

> Show that $\mathbb Z$ with the finite-closed topology is a $T_1$-space but not a $T_2$-space.

For every $z \in \mathbb Z$ we have that {z} is closed in the finite-closed topology and so $\mathbb Z$ with the finite-closed topology is a $T_1$-space.

I am not sure how to show that it is not a $T_2$-space though.

Comment: HINT: Show that if $U$ and $V$ are non-empty open sets, $U\cap V\ne\varnothing$.

Answer (score 2):

Given two points $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb Z$, the complementary of a neighborood $U(x)$ is a finite set (it's closed), and the same for a neighborood $V(y)$. So $U(x)\cap V(y)$ can't be empty for reasons of cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

As Giuseppe notes, infinity is the key. All closed sets in this topology are finite since a finite union of closed sets is finite. So **ALL** non-empty open sets are co-final (i.e. contain all but finite elements of Z.) Any two infinite co-final sets must intersect infinitely often. So $T_2$ is impossible.